# AVPlayer Video Gravity Positioning?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avplayer

In my application, I have created a custom video player using `AVPlayer`. This works great, and there are no problems. However, I allow the `AVPlayer` video gravity to be changed by a double tap.

When it is changed to `AVPlayerGravityResizeAspect`, the video is centered in the middle. Is there any way to make the video stay the same size (resize aspect, not resize aspect fill), but move it to the bottom or top of the `AVPlayer`?

```
- (IBAction)zoomTapped:(id)sender {
    if (self.player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        if ([((AVPlayerLayer *)[self.playerView layer]).videoGravity isEqualToString : AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect]) {
            [self.zoomButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zoom-out.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self.playerView layer]).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
        }
        else {
            [self.zoomButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zoom-in.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self.playerView layer]).videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;

            ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self.playerView layer]).bounds = ((AVPlayerLayer *)[self.playerView layer]).bounds;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not one of your choices. The three gravity choices you get are the three gravity choices you get. However, there is no need for such a feature, because you can position the player layer *itself* wherever you like, so you can position *it* at the bottom or top in relation to some view or layer.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I have videos that vary in height, so if I select resize aspect, there is black bars at the top and bottom that vary in size depending on the video. How would I know how much to move them?

Comment: You'd find out the size (rectangle) of the movie and use a little arithmetic.

Comment: The fact that you have black bars suggests that you are already not taking sufficient control of the situation. An asset track has a `naturalSize` that tells you its aspect ratio...

Comment: The videos are imported, I have no control over what size they are shot in. Thank you, I will use this.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear: I meant, you will not see bars if you will size the layer to match the aspect ratio of the movie.